# Publishing a simple Java library to Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, artifactory

I might be missing something major here. However, I am struggling to publish a simple library to a maven repository (which will be consumed by other maven based projects in the organization)

The best guide I've found is on the official Gradle website: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

However, there are still many unanswered questions:

- Is there no way to differentiate between SNAPSHOT and release builds other than to manually include the if-else statement?
- What is `from components.java`? IDEA gives no autocomplete or documentation on most of these DSLs (unlike Maven, where the code intelligence works well)
- How do I publish to a private repository that requires authentication? I understand somewhere there must be a block that uses:

  ```
      username = "${artifactory_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_password}"
  ```

With the values being read from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

But where do I put this block?

Overall, I feel like I a missing something here, maybe some documentation that is popularly read ... using maven itself the process is fairly straight-forward and the official documentation makes the process relatively painless

With Gradle, I feel like the simplest publish to a repository requires quite a lot what feels like customized logic when my intuition says something so common must already be encapsulated in a plugin with reasonable defaults

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you've found your solution already, but my answer will aim to give you detailed answers to your questions.

> Is there no way to differentiate between SNAPSHOT and release builds other than to manually include the if-else statement?

Correct. An `if-else` statement is exactly what you need to distinguish between a snapshot and release build. Gradle itself does not provide any sort of versioning functionality. That is left to you to handle or a plugin such as [Nebula Release](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin).

> What is `from components.java`

- The `from` is a method call from [`AbstractCopyTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#from-java.lang.Object...-) which the [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html) task type is a subclass of.
- `components` is again another method call. You are actually calling `getComponents()` of [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getComponents--).

  - `components.java` is sugar for `components.getByName("java")`. This works because of dynamic/magic of [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org).

> IDEA gives no autocomplete or documentation on most of these DSLs (unlike Maven, where the code intelligence works well)

This is due to the dynamic/weak typing of Groovy. The `build.gradle` file is written using Groovy. IntelliJ does try to infer the type of your build script, but it can't fully. Luckily you can now write your build script using Kotlin:

- https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-build-logic-from-groovy-to-kotlin/
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html

I highly suggest using the Kotlin DSL going forward. You will know *exactly* where everything is coming from.

> How do I publish to a private repository that requires authentication?

Unfortunately the docs for the `maven-publish` plugin merely mentions it in a single sentence. Even so, it just directs you to API docs which aren't always helpful, but you were able to figure it out.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

> *You can also configure any authentication details that are required to connect to the repository. See [MavenArtifactRepository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html) for more details.*

And finally:

> (...) the values being read from ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Gradle will go out of its way to resolve a property. `gradle.properties` is just one of many locations that Gradle will look for properties. You can see more details under the **Properties** section on top [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html).

---

I'd like to finish off by providing a complete example of your answer using the Kotlin DSL. Also using the `buildscript { }` is a legacy method of applying plugins as noted [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application). You should use the newer/preferred `plugins { }` block going forward. More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block).

```
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.31"
}

group = "com.company"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

tasks.wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "5.6.1"
    distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}

val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            artifactId = "some-artifactId"
            from(components["java"])
            artifact(sourcesJar.get())
            pom {
                name.set("Project Name")
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://company.jfrog.io/company/maven-local")
            credentials {
                username = property("artifactory_user") as String
                password = property("artifactory_password") as String
            }
        }
    }
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question here is the bare bones minimum to publish to a private repo:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

group 'com.company'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.9'
    distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'some-artifactId'
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            pom {
                name = 'Project Name'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "https://company.jfrog.io/company/maven-local"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0"
    compile "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.8.0"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1"
    testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.0"
}
```